# Rendering a Django Form through a TemplateTag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, templatetags

I'm trying to render a form through a templatetag in django so that I can I can render the form on multiple pages. However, I get the following error when I try to render it:

_ init_() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given).

This arises, I believe, from the templatetag not passing the user information to the form. The authenticated user should be the user passed to the form.

Forms.py:

```
class ExpressionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Expression
        exclude = ('user',)

    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'cols': 19}), required=False, label=_('Body'))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpressionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['expressiontype'].queryset = ExpressionType.objects.all()
        self.fields['expressiontype'].required = True
```

And in my templatetag .py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('expressions/templatetags/express.html')
def express():
    return {'form': ExpressionForm()}
```

How would I go about passing the user to the form through the templatetag? Thanks :)

Comment: according to your __init__ you should pass user to the form: ExpressionForm(user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation details how to [pass arguments into custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag).

Your other option is to adjust your tag [so it is aware of the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).